# Count files each user has uploaded and approved

Tags: django, django-admin, action

I am building a Django app for uploading files. I would like to be able to count the number of files a users has and which are approved. I have a model with a Boolean 'approved' field. This model is in admin.py.

[image]

In admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import FileModel
from .forms import FileForm
class FileModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FileForm
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'categories', 'pub_date', 'submitted_date', 'author', 'user', 'approved', 'upload', 'vote')
    # pass                                                                                                                                            
    list_display = ['title', 'approved', 'author', 'user', 'categories', 'description', 'pub_date', 'submitted_date', 'upload', 'vote']
admin.site.register(FileModel, FileModelAdmin)
```

I would like an integer in another model 'new_user_model', which is in another app, to increase an integer field 'files' by one when a file is approved in the admin site. This way I could keep track of how many files have been approved for each user.

```
class NewUserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User)                                                                                                                  
    files = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The model for the files,

```
class FileModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    submitted_date = models.DateTimeField('date submitted')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user =  models.ForeignKey(User, default=6)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    upload = models.FileField().....................
...................................................
```

So I want the files field in new_user_model to increase by one when a file is 'approved' and the save button hit in the admin site. Also if the 'approved' is unchecked I would need the 'files' field to reduce by one.

How could this be done?

Updated:

Ultimately I would like to be able to display the number of files a user has on the site.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't prefer to have an `approved_by` ForeignKey in the FileModel? This way you can count how many files someone has approved, and know _which_ files they have approved.

Comment: Ok this sounds like the correct way to do it. So this would be a foreignkey to User?

Comment: I was trying to do it in such a way that I wouldn't have to count the number of approved files for each user. Instead I would like to update the number of approved files each time they are approved in the admin. This should be less processing and quicker. But it means the the number of files needs to be already available. And that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: I would need to do a comparison and see if the files is already approved. If there is a difference then either increase or decrease the 'files' value.

Comment: Are you saying each file can be approved multiple times by difference users? If it's just one person who approves once, you'd want a ForeignKey to User, if multiple users can approve the file you want a ManyToMany field to User.

Comment: Each file belongs to one user. And each file can only be approved once and by one user.

Comment: No sorry the files can only be approved by the admin, no one else.

Comment: Admin is just a field on the User model - if you only make the action available on the admin site, only admins will be able to approve.

Comment: Yes that is what i want here.

Comment: Did you try adding the admin actions per my answer? Those are only on the admin site.

Comment: Ahhhh I updated Django 1.10 from 1.9 and url patterns are deprecated since 1.8 and not used in 1.10. So I'm a bit stuck and can't get basic 'runserver' to work. .... Probably about to get in trouble here for not making this a chat. But thank you for the FileModelAdmin code, can't wait to try it. I will let you know when I get Django working again.Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125932/discussion-between-ofey-and-jens-astrup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a chance to complete this?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import FileModel
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import FileForm
from crudapp.models import NewUserModel
#from django.db import models

from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected as delete_selected_

# see https://gist.github.com/rudyryk/4190318
# overrides and recreates delete_selected
def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    if not modeladmin.has_delete_permission(request):
        raise PermissionDenied
    if request.POST.get('post'):
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.delete()
    else:
        return delete_selected_(modeladmin, request, queryset)
delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected objects"

class FileModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FileForm
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'categories', 'pub_date', 'submitted_date', 'author', 'user', 'approved', 'upload', 'vote')
    # pass
    list_display = ['title', 'approved', 'author', 'user', 'categories', 'description', 'pub_date', 'submitted_date', 'upload', 'vote']
    actions = ['approve_files', 'delete_selected']

    def approve_files(self, request, obj):
        for qs in obj:
            print "run number..."
            author = qs.author
            adminApproved = qs.approved # approved status on admin site
            userInstance = User.objects.get(username=author)
            id = qs.id
            item = FileModel.objects.get(pk=id)
            approved = item.approved # approved status in FileModel
            id = userInstance.id
            item = NewUserModel.objects.get(user_id=id)
            print "existentialism"
            print "approved: %s" %(approved)
            print "adminApproved: %s" %(adminApproved)
            if(approved == False):
                item.files += 1
            item.save()
        obj.update(approved = True)
        #NewUserModel.save()
        #obj.save()

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        id = obj.id
        item = FileModel.objects.get(pk=id)
        # Test if file 'approved' has been changed on admin site
        if(item.approved != obj.approved):
            author = obj.author
            userInstance = User.objects.get(username=author)
            id = userInstance.id
            item = NewUserModel.objects.get(user_id=id)
            if(obj.approved == True):
                item.files += 1
                item.save()
            else:
                item.files -= 1
                item.save()
        obj.save()

    def delete_model(self, request, queryset):
        print "we are inside delete_model()"
        author = queryset.author
        userInstance = User.objects.get(username=author)
        id = queryset.id
        item = FileModel.objects.get(pk=id)
        approved = item.approved # approved status in FileModel
        #filename=obj.profile_name+".xml"
        #os.remove(os.path.join(obj.type,filename))
        id = userInstance.id
        item = NewUserModel.objects.get(user_id=id)
        # -1 for file in filemodel only if approved
        if approved == True:
            item.files -= 1
            item.save()
            print "inner part of delete_model()"
        queryset.delete()

    # The 'Delete selected' action
    def delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        print "we are inside delete_selected()"
        for obj in queryset:
            author = obj.author
            adminApproved = obj.approved # approved status on admin site
            userInstance = User.objects.get(username=author)
            id = obj.id
            item = FileModel.objects.get(pk=id)
            approved = item.approved # approved status in FileModel
            id = userInstance.id
            item = NewUserModel.objects.get(user_id=id)
            # For the case where a file is deleted but was approved yet
            if approved == True:
                item.files -= 1
                print "inner part of delete_selected()"
                item.save()
            print "running for each iteration of obj"
        queryset.delete()

admin.site.register(FileModel, FileModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [custom admin action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#writing-actions) which marks the files as approved. These are passed a request object which you can use to grab your `NewUserModel`. (You may want to remove 'Model' from your Model names, seems a bit redundant, but personal taste I suppose :)

```
class FileModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FileForm
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'categories', 'pub_date', 'submitted_date',   'author', 'user', 'approved', 'upload', 'vote')
    # ....
    actions = ['approve_files']
    def approve_files(self, request, queryset):
        # Queryset can be greater than 1
        queryset.update(approved=True)
        user = request.user
        # I keep wanting to put underscores in...
        user_files_count = user.newusermodel.files
        # Get the amount of Files in the query, may be more than one
        user.newusermodel.files = user_files_count + queryset.count()  
        user.newusermodel.save()
```

That being said, if you did want to keep track of who approved what:

```
class FileModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ...
    approved_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

then the admin action above would just be:

```
def approve_files(self, request, queryset):
    # Queryset can be greater than 1
    queryset.update(approved_by=request.user)
```

and you would be able to get the user's file count by doing:

```
user = Users.objects.get(id=some_id)
file_count = user.filemodel.all().count()
```

Comment: Using just the first block of code you gave, I get the error

"RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /adminfileuploader/filemodel/
User has no newusermodel." 

and a problem with,

"user_files_count = user.newusermodel.files"

Comment: I did try it with underscores, "new_user_model", but no luck,

Comment: I forgot, from crudapp.models import NewUserModel

Comment: Still things to fix, but it is working enough now to play with. I will post if and when i make a bit of progress. Thanks