# Linode Django uwsgi Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, linode

The following setup is only letting me see the default Nginx html page. How can I get to Django?

I've been following Linode's documentation on how to set this up (and numerous other tutorials), but they don't use systemd, so things are a bit different.

https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I am using Linode with Fedora24. I have installed my virutalenv at
/home/ofey/djangoenv and activated it,
Django is installed using pip at 
/home/ofey/qqiProject
Into the virtualenv I've installed uwsgi.
Firstly,
/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ofey/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This executes,

/etc/uwsgi/sites/qqiProject.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = qqiProject
base = /home/ofey

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/djangoenv
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 2

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

Also,

/etc/nginx/sites-available/qqiProject

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name qqiresources.com www.qqiresources.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/qqiProject;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/django/qqiProject/qqiProject.sock;
    }
}
```

The file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf has not been changed.

The user is ofey, I've used,

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
$ sudo systemctl start uwsgi.service
```

Started Django with,

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

To Django's settings.py I turned off debugging and added a host

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['qqiresources.com']
```

I have also created a symbolic link,

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/qqiProject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: In qqiProject.ini you have  '/home/ofey', but in /etc/nginx/sites-available/qqiProject it's  'home/django/'. Maybe that's your mistake?

Comment: Thank you for finding that error. I corrected but unfortunately still no luck.

Comment: Did you restart everything after changing the configs?

Comment: I simplified the problem by first getting a basic hello world python script to work with uwsgi. Then I added Django successfully and as soon as I figure out how to server staticfiles and cdn's in Django I will add nginx. So I am unfortunately not ready for it all together yet. but I will post when i get there. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063646/count-files-each-user-has-uploaded-and-approved?noredirect=1#comment67413185_40063646

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me, however I am not sure if this is the correct or most efficient way to do it, especially where the sockets are concerned.

systemd runs the uwsgi.service and can be started with,

```
$ sudo systemctl start uwsgi.service
```

Sometimes it is necessary to reload systemd using,

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

/etc/sysemd/system/uwsgi.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ofey/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This calls the binary inside my django virtual environment directory with,

ExecStart=/home/ofey/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi

and also takes us to /etc/uwsgi/sites where the uwsgi configuration files is called djangoForum.ini

/etc/uwsgi/sites/djangoForum.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = djangoForum
base = /home/ofey

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/djangoenv
module = crudProject.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 2

socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

Django is at /home/ofey/djangoForum and my django project is at /home/ofey/djangoForum/crudProject

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
events {
     worker_connections 1024;
}

http{

 upstream django {
    # connect to this socket
    # server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;    # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:3031;      # for a web port socket
    }

server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name example.com;   # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    #Max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
                alias /home/ofey/djangoForum/fileuploader/uploaded_files;      # your Django project's media files
    }

        location /static {
                alias /home/ofey/djangoForum/noAppBoundStaticDirectory;     # your Django project's static files
        }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        # uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # or the uwsgi_params you installed manually
        }
  }
}
```

nginx can be turned on with,

```
$ sudo systemctl start nginx.service
```

'start' can be replaced with, 'restart' or 'stop'.

These configuration files for uwsgi and nginx worked for me.

Useful links:

https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281

https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04