# Basic uwsgi configuration with Linode

Tags: python-2.7, uwsgi, linode

I am following a tutorial on configuring Django, nginx and uwsgi.
https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281

The first part of which involves configuring uwsgi to run this python file 
/home/ofey/djangoenv/bin/test.py

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return "Hello world"
```

djangoenv is the virtualenv directory.

It contains the binary uwsgi, which was installed to this environment using

```
$ pip install uwsgi
```

Just to note, I have stopped nginx with,

```
$ sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

and also stopped uwsgi which was running as a service with systemd.

```
$ sudo systemctl stop uwsgi
```

Running test.py and the output,

```
(djangoenv) [ofey@ofeyspi bin]$ uwsgi --http :8000 --master --wsgi-file test.py
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14 (64bit) on [Tue Nov 29 21:54:09 2016] ***
compiled with version: 6.2.1 20160916 (Red Hat 6.2.1-2) on 28 November 2016 14:39:40
os: Linux-4.8.6-x86_64-linode78 #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 14:51:21 EDT 2016
nodename: ofeyspi
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ofey/djangoenv/bin
detected binary path: /home/ofey/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 7982
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 4
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:41335 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Sep 29 2016, 13:30:34)  [GCC 6.2.1 20160916 (Red Hat 6.2.1-2)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xb72990
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145520 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xb72990 pid: 11493 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 11493)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 11494, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 11495)
```

I would expect to see 'hello world' at http://qqiresources.com:8000
but nothing.

I do know that qqiresources.com is working because I see the nginx default homepage when I turn on nginx.

This is running on Linode with a virtual deployment of Fedora 24.

I did previously post a question trying to configure Django, wsgi and nginx on Linode but I think I need to figure out the above simpler situation first.
[Linode Django uwsgi Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855861/linode-django-uwsgi-nginx)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Guessing here: Since uwsgi isn't meant to be exposed directly on the internet, by default it will listen on 127.0.0.1 and that means that you won't be able to access it via the internet. Check to see if you can bind it to the external IP address of your machine. Also, check to see if the port 8000 is open on your firewall (if there's one active). Try a simple `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` and see if you can connect from the outside.

Comment: @Tiago thanks for looking at this.

Comment: (djangoenv) [ofey@ofeyspi bin]$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...

Comment: Unfortunately nothing at qqiresources.com:8000 which suggests the port is not open. How do i do that? Back to the Linode dashboard, I'll have a look there.

Comment: That's not a config on Linode's dashboard. You have to look your distro default config and see how to open that port. Something to do with `iptables`, I imagine. If you just want to test uwsgi, run it with sudo and make it liste on port 80.

Comment: This works with sudo and port 80 which is great. I would need to work with the iptables to open port 8000 to get this to work. But really when I do get nginx added only that needs to work on port 80. I suppose it will talk to a socket, which will talk to uwsgi which will in turn talk to Django on port 8000, but all internally. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that's the proper way. It's fairly easy to config nginx do proxy requests to your uwsgi server.